# HTML Table Filter

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, filter

I am using `HTML Table Filter` to filter my tables from a SQL query using PHP ( http://tablefilter.free.fr ) for a ticket system.

As I am getting more than 4000 rows now, the page is really slow.
Is there a way to load the rows using AJAX without breaking the search and pagination functionalities?

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to use the [DataTables](https://datatables.net/) plugin for jQuery.
You can initialize the table and put in the rows dynamically using ajax calls.

If you don't want to load all the data in one request, you can use the [Deferred loading of data feature](https://datatables.net/examples/server_side/defer_loading.html).

Comment: But it will still be slow with 4000+ rows. What I want is to have something that get - for example - the 20 first rows, but still with a pagination system. Also with the search that would search not only on the 20 rows displayed but to all the database. Thanks for your reply.